# Concept of a variable as a name?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic

Is it wrong to think of a variable simply as a symbol in an expression that we replace with another expression? Is a variable only a placeholder for an object's 'proper name' such as '5' etc or is it a more general name for the object itself, for example the expression $2x$ could have $x=2$ and still we can retain the $x$ as $x$ is now a name for the number $2$ in it's own right just as importantly as $2$, $1+1$ etc.

More explicitly if I see $x+1$ does $x$ mean that we can put only the number's 'proper name' or that any expression for the number can be substituted in?

Comment: For context see the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4511613/variable-as-a-name?noredirect=1#comment9473014_4511613). Please don't delete and repost, rather edit a question. A polynomial, like $f=3x^2+5x+7\in \Bbb Z[x]$ has $x$ as a variable, and as such we don't want to replace $x$ by an element of the underlying domain. Of course, we may view it as a function, and then we can talk about $f(2)$. But I think it is "wrong" to consider a variable simply as an expression that we replace. $\Bbb Z[x]$ is a polynomial ring in one variable.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think that depends _entirely_ on your level. The meaning of "a variable" to middle schoolers and to graduate students don't have to be the same. Thinking of them as placeholders will serve most people for years before they ever encounter the need for more nuance.

Comment: Yes a variable is a placeholder, like a pronoun in natural language. "x=2" is like "it is red"; it needs a context that gives reference to te variable (pronoun) in order that the expression has meaning.

Comment: @DietrichBurde in polynomial rings generally I've heard of the term 'indeterminate' which I don't necessarily think of as a variable as it does not really represent anything other than itself.

Comment: context is key.  In an equation it's known, provided it's the only variable.  Otherwise, in an expression it can be considered a degree of freedom.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is on a pre-algebra context -- understanding may change as you progress.

Suppose you have $x=2$. This effectively translate to $\texttt{Define x to be 2}$

Under the context that $x=2$, $x$ and the literal constant $2$ may be used interchangeably.

Suppose you are solving the equation $x^2-2x+1=1$. Here $x$ is still *defined* to a literal constant that you don't know. Every effort you make in solving this equation must keep $x$'s value.

So you may transform it to $x^2=2x$, here, $x$ is still defined to be that unknown value. It is still nothing more than a mere symbol. In the transformation process, you didn't change $x$'s definition. This is where most algebraic operations takes place.